# Submitting multiple forms with one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, forms

I've looked at all the threads that already exist on this topic and have not been able to come up with a solution for my case.

I have multiple forms rendering with the help of Handlebars like this:

```
<ul>
  {{#each listRecords}}

      <form id="form{{id}}" action="/expand-list-records-save/{{../listId}}/{{id}}" method="POST">
          <div class="record-box">
              <li>{{recordTitle}} by {{artistName}} ({{releaseYear}})
                <br>
                  <div>
                      <label>Paste media embed code here:</label>
                      <textarea class="form-control form-control-lg" name="embeddedmedia" cols="30" rows="10">{{embeddedMedia}}</textarea>
                  </div>
                <br>
                <br>
              </li>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

  {{/each}}
</ul>
<input id="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" type="submit" value="Submit embed code" >

<script>
  $(document).ready(() => {
    $('#submit').click(function submitAllForms() {
      for (var i=0; i < document.forms.length; i++) {
        console.log(`submitting ${document.forms[i].id}`)
        document.forms[i].submit();
      }
    })
  })
</script>
```

my Node.js + Express.js route looks like this

```
router.route('/expand-list-records-save/:listId/:recordId')
  .post((req, res) => {
      // console.log(req)
      Record.findOne({
        where: {
          id: req.params.recordId
        }
      }).then(result => {
        // console.log(req.body)
          result.update({
            embeddedMedia: req.body.embeddedmedia
          })

      }).then(() => {
          console.log("sending list to view")
          sendListDataToView({ params: {id: req.params.listId} }, res, 'view-list')

        })
    })
```

I'm having a few problems. First of all, this logic only executes a POST request for the item that the very last form on the page is for. Why is it that the console.log works for every single instance in my loop when iterating through all the document forms? From what I know, I think I need to use AJAX here somehow to execute all the POST requests. And the second main thing that I don't think is giving me problems at this point, but will once I get the first issue solved, is that my route is not written to handle a batch of requests like I need it to.

**UPDATE**
Upon a recommendation in comments, I decided try and write an Ajax request to post all of the forms to a separate route which will handle it from there. How do I pass an array of forms to the `data` parameter? I get the `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error this way:

```
  $(document).ready(() => {
    $('#submit').click(function submitAllForms() {
      $.ajax({
      type: 'POST', 
      url: window.location.origin + $('h3')[0].innerText,
      data: document.forms,
      success: (data) => {
        console.log(data)
        }
      })
    })
  })
```

After going through some other examples, I tried rewriting original submit script like this. And, in this case, it does not pick up the `action` attribute.

```
  $(document).ready(() => {
    $('#submit').click(function submitAllForms() {
      $('form').each(() => {
        var that = $(this);
        $.post(that.attr('action'), that.serialize())
      })
    })
  })
```

Comment: Do you really want to execute `document.forms.length` separate form submissions?  That is likely not a very good design.  Instead, you should probably implement a new route that handles data from multiple forms in one POST.  Then, you can collect the data from all the forms with Javascript and use jQuery's `$.ajax()` to send one POST with all the data in it.

Comment: I'm definitely not insisting on that, document.forms.length was just one way I managed to makes at least submission of one form work. I theoretically understand what you are suggestion, but will need to some time to try and actually implement it.

Comment: @jfriend00 in the Ajax request like that, how do I send all the forms. I've tried `data: document.forms` and it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have finally come up with a solution, if anyone is interested. Perhaps not prettiest, but it works.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(() => {
    $('#submit').click(function submitAllForms() {

      var counter = 0; 
      var totalForms = $('form').length;
      $('form').each((i, form) => {

        const redirectIfDone = () => {
          if (counter === totalForms) {
            alert("all forms updated successfully")
            window.location.replace(window.location.origin + '/list/' + $('h3')[0].innerText)
          }   
        }

        if (!($(form).find('textarea').val())) {
          counter++
          redirectIfDone();
          return true;
        } else {
          $.ajax({
          type: 'POST', 
          url: $(form).attr('action'),
          data: $(form).serialize(),
          success: (data) => {
            counter++;
            redirectIfDone();
          }
          })
        }
      })
    })
  })
</script>
```

Virtually no changes to the route. Overall, I'm still interested in seeing other possible solutions.

```
router.route('/expand-list-records-save/:listId/:recordId')
  .post((req, res) => {
      Record.findOne({
        where: {
          id: req.params.recordId
        }
      }).then(result => {
          result.update({
            embeddedMedia: req.body.embeddedmedia
          })
          res.end()
      })
    })
```